# NSubstitute: Received Calls asserts wrongly

Tags: nsubstitute

I've created this test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UsersTests
{
    private Core.Kernel coreKernel;
    private Core.Configuration.ICoreConfiguration coreConfiguration;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this.coreConfiguration = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<Core.Configuration.ICoreConfiguration>();
        this.coreKernel = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<Core.Kernel>(this.coreConfiguration);

        this.coreKernel.Initialize();
    }

    [Test]
    public void AddUserTest()
    {
        Core.Communication.Entities.UserIdentity receivedUserIdentity = new Core.Communication.Entities.UserIdentity("user1", "passwd1");

        ((Core.Communication.ICoreService)this.coreKernel).AddUserIdentity(receivedUserIdentity);
        this.coreKernel.Received(100).AddUser(Arg.Is<Core.Identity.UserIdentity>(u => u.UserId.Equals(receivedUserIdentity.UserId)));
    }
}
```

where `Core.Kernel` is:

```
public partial class Kernel : Core.IKernel
{
    public Kernel(Configuration.ICoreConfiguration configuration)
            : this(configuration, null, Enumerable.Empty<Type>())
    {

    }

    public Kernel(Configuration.ICoreConfiguration configuration, Communication.ICoreService service, IEnumerable<Type> producerTypes)
    {
        if (configuration == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("configuration object must be provided", "configuration");

        if (producerTypes.Any(t => !t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Core.Extensibility.AbstractProducerPlugin))))
            throw new ArgumentException("All types must inherit from AbstractProducerPlugin", "plugins");


        this.state = KernelState.initializing;

        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.service = service ?? this;
        this.producerTypes = producerTypes;

        this.backends = new Dictionary<Core.Identity.DomainIdentity, Backend.Infrastructure.IBackend>();
    }

    internal virtual void AddUser(Core.Identity.UserIdentity userIdentity) {...}
}
```

Nevertheless, `this.coreKernel.Received(100).AddUser(...` is not called 100 times, only one. What am I doing wrong?

I mean, I'm not trying to make 100 calls to `AddUser`. I'm checking `AddUser` should be called 100 times. So, assertion should fail.

**EDIT**

Guess this code (`Core.IKernel.AddUserIdentity(...)` implementation):

```
public class Core.Kernel {
    public override void Core.IKernel.AddUserIdentity(UserIdentity userIdentity) {
        this.AddUser(userIdentity); <<----- AddUser(...) is called
    }
}
```

I think the problem is related with:

1. `Core.Kernel` implements `Core.IKernel`. `Core.IKernel` has `AddUserIdentity(...)` method.
2. I'm mocking `Core.Kernel` instead of mocking a `Core.IKernel`.
3. According to `Core.IKernel.AddUserIdentity(...)` method implementation `AddUser` should ne reached.
4. `AddUser` is an `internal virtual` method of `Core.Kernel`. It's not an implementation of any method interface.

I want to assert `AddUser` is called once when `AddUserIdentity` is reached.

Other questions about mocking:

1. `For<T>` where T is a concrete class -> `virtual` methods are replaced? no `virtual` methods are executed?
2. `ForPartsOf<T>` where T is a concrete class -> Which parts of this class are mocked (`virtual methods`, overrided interface methods)?

Comment: I can't tell from this code why the assertion is not failing, but thought I should mention you appear to be substituting for `Core.Kernel` but want to test some of the logic in it. For example, you are calling `coreKernel.Initialise()` and `AddUserIdentity(...)` on the substitute, which will not run any actual logic if it is `virtual`.

You may want to check the documentation on [partial substitutes](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/) to achieve this. Or better yet, refactor the design to allow you to new up a real `Core.Kernel` and test its interactions with its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks David for your comments. Could you take a look on post? I've edited it in order to add some details.

Answer (score 0):

It is only called once because you are only calling `AddUser` once. The `Received` assertion checks how many times it has been called, it doesn't tell NSubstitue to call your method 100 times, you need to do that manually :)

> NSubstitute also gives you the option of asserting a specific number of calls were received by passing an integer to Received(). This will throw if the substitute does not receive exactly that many matching calls

http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/

Comment: Thanks user9993 for your comment. I understand what's the code do, nevertheless, the assertion should fail, nevertheless it success. `AddUser` should be called once after having executed `AddUserIdentity`.